# css - block out of control if the number of line is different

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

```css
.inDB {
  background-color: #53354A;
  color: #53354A;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-one-content">
  <ul id="gt" class="meta_data">
    <h2 style="color:#859900; padding:30px">No Meta Data</h2>
    <li><button class="inDB"></button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB"></button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB"></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

You can see the first button is slightly higher than other 2. Because it has only 1 line as text content

How can I fix the problem and make all in same line.

Comment: Put min-height for your in your css.

Comment: I think the button all has same height its because the text

Comment: can you post your whole css codes? for `<li>` `<ul>`

Comment: Please show us the code according to your screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline elements are aligned to the first text line per default. You can do the following:

1. You can set

   ```
   li {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   ```

   That way, your `<li>` elements (and the containing buttons) will be aligned to the top of their container
2. Don't use `<h2>` as direct child of an `<ul>` for [no other child element than `<li>` is allowed for `<ul>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) (See [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul))
3. Check your markup in general and make sure, that no other CSS rules overwrite your vertical alignment

[image]

Here a working example:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#section-two-content li {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.inDB {
  background-color: #53354A;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
No vertical align:
<div id="section-one-content">
  <ul id="gt" class="meta_data">
    <li><button class="inDB">test</button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB">test<br>test</button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB">test</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>

vertical align:
<div id="section-two-content">
  <ul id="gt" class="meta_data">
    <li><button class="inDB">test</button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB">test<br>test</button></li>
    <li><button class="inDB">test</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it just not working i think its because of the text. you see if you have text for more than 1 line. the button move down

Comment: Exactly this problem is addressed by the example. You see the second button has two lines of text and the other buttons only one. With vertical-align, the button with more text lines is adjusted to the top

Comment: Have you checked, if any other rules overwrite your definition? Which browser?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.flex-container {
     display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }
```

```html
 
  
      <h2 style="color:#859900; padding:30px" >No Meta Data</h2>
 <div id="section-one-content flex-container">
      <button class="flex-item inDB">a</button>
      <button class="flex-item inDB">b</button>
      <button class="flex-item inDB">c</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using min-height property, please try min-height like this

```
.inDB{
  background-color: #53354A;
  color: #53354A;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  min-height: 110px;
  width:130px;
}
```